Encriptar un archivo generado con Maatwebsite
Hola necesito de su ayuda, estoy trabajando con Maatwebsite y sin problemas puedo descargarlo de la siguiente forma.
return Excel::download(new SmsExport($elements), $filename, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
Lo que quiero es encriptarlo para que después al abrirlo le pida la contraseña al usuario, pero cuando se descarga me sale error "Excel no puede abrir el archivo porque el formato o la extensión no son validos. Compruebe que el archivo no se ha dañado y que la extensión y el formato  del archivo coinciden". Este es mi código:
<?php
public function tableExport($ext)
{
    abort_if(!in_array($ext, ['csv', 'xlsx', 'pdf']), Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    
    $elements = $this->elementsQuery
        ->unless($this->selectAll, fn ($query) => $query->whereKey($this->selectedElements))
        ->pluck('id');

    $filename = 'archivo.' . $ext; //Modificar según el modelo

    $user_email = auth()->user()->email;

    $generate_password = Str::random(10);

    $password = Hash::make($generate_password);

    Mail::to($user_email)->send(new sendEncryptPassword($password)); 

    $export = new SmsExport($elements);

    $tempFilePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'export');

    Excel::download($export, $filename.'.xlsx', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);

    $encryptedData = Crypt::encrypt(file_get_contents($tempFilePath));

    unlink($tempFilePath);

    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($encryptedData) {
        echo $encryptedData;
    }, $filename);
}
?>

